# Reading(?) escape chars

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a .php file and replace the hex'd chars.
The php file is of the following format:

```
<?php ${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x6ana\x76\x79\x77\x70\x74\x62x"] ... ?>
```

The problem is that it messes up the escape chars ( \" )

My code so far:

```
while(i<=filelen)
{
    if(str[i]=='\\' && str[i+1]=='x' && (str[i+2]>=48 && str[i+2]<=57 || str[i+2]>=97 && str[i+2]<=122) )
    {
        string temp(str.substr(i,4));
        stringstream k;
        temp.erase(0,2);
        string temp2;
        temp2=hexToAscii(temp[0],temp[1]);
        output.append(temp2);
        i+=4;
    }
    else 
    {
        stringstream k;
        k<<str[i];
        output.append(k.str());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For the sample input you gave, the code you showed produced `<?php ${"GBEBABS"}["\`navywptbx"] ... ?>`. If this isn't what you expected, what *do* you expect?

Comment: It decodes most of the code correctly but lines that contain the escape char \ get messed up.

Comment: Then please post a failure-inducing line together with what you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: encoded: ${${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x79\x6b\x6ehl\x68r\x70\x77\x66vj"]}="<img \x73\x72c\x3d\x22".e_PLUGIN."\x72\x65\x63\x6f\x72\x64s\x2f\x69\x6d\x61\x67es\x2ff\x6c\x61\x67\x73/".getdemo_usercountry(${${"\x47L\x4fB\x41L\x53"}["f\x79c\x79r\x79\x63\x65\x75"]}).".\x67\x69\x66\x22\x20bor\x64er\x3d\x220\" \x61\x6c\x74=\"\x22 /\x3e\x20<a\x20\x68\x72\x65f=\"".e_BASE."\x75\x73er\x2eph\x70?\x69d\x2e".${${"\x47L\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["fy\x63\x79r\x79\x63\x65\x75"]}."\">".${${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x64\x66\x76lt\x79v\x68h\x68y"]}["user_n\x61me"]."\x3c\x2fa\x3e";

Comment: decoded: ${${"GLOBALS"}["yknhlhrpwfvj"]}="<img src="".e_PLUGIN."records/images/flags/".getdemo_usercountry(${${"GLOBALS"}["fycyryceu"]}).".gif" border="0\" alt=\"" /> <a href=\"".e_BASE."user.php?id.".${${"GLOBALS"}["fycyryceu"]}."\">".${${"GLOBALS"}["dfvltyvhhhy"]}["user_name"]."</a>";

Answer (score 0):

This calls for a regular expression!

Comment: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.' - J. Zawinski

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem you have. For what it's worth, here's a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (well, it's not as short as it could have been, because I wanted to preserve your original code, so I had to introduce a `hexToAscii` function etc. - you could've just used [`strtoul`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtoul.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int hexToInt( char ch )
{
    if ( ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' ) {
        return ch - '0';
    }
    if ( ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f' ) {
        return 10 + ch - 'a';
    }
    if ( ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F' ) {
        return 10 + ch - 'A';
    }
    return -1;
}

std::string hexToAscii( char ch1, char ch2 )
{
    std::string result;
    result.push_back( static_cast<char>( hexToInt( ch1 ) * 16 + hexToInt( ch2 ) ) );
    return result;
}

void f( const std::string &str, const std::string::size_type filelen, std::string &output )
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0;
    using namespace std;
// ---- Verbatim copy starts
while(i<=filelen)
{
    if(str[i]=='\\' && str[i+1]=='x' && (str[i+2]>=48 && str[i+2]<=57 || str[i+2]>=97 && str[i+2]<=122) )
    {
        string temp(str.substr(i,4));
        stringstream k;
        temp.erase(0,2);
        string temp2;
        temp2=hexToAscii(temp[0],temp[1]);
        output.append(temp2);
        i+=4;
    }
    else 
    {
        stringstream k;
        k<<str[i];
        output.append(k.str());
        i++;
    }
}
// --- Verbatim copy ends
}

int main()
{
    //std::string input = "<?php ${\"\\x47\\x4c\\x4f\\x42\\x41\\x4cS\"}[\"\\x6ana\\x76\\x79\\x77\\x70\\x74\\x62x\"] ... ?>";
    std::string input = "${${\"\\x47\\x4cO\\x42A\\x4c\\x53\"}[\"\\x79\\x6b\\x6ehl\\x68r\\x70\\x77\\x66vj\"]}=\"<img \\x73\\x72c\\x3d\\x22\".e_PLUGIN.\"\\x72\\x65\\x63\\x6f\\x72\\x64s\\x2f\\x69\\x6d\\x61\\x67es\\x2ff\\x6c\\x61\\x67\\x73/\".getdemo_usercountry(${${\"\\x47L\\x4fB\\x41L\\x53\"}[\"f\\x79c\\x79r\\x79\\x63\\x65\\x75\"]}).\".\\x67\\x69\\x66\\x22\\x20bor\\x64er\\x3d\\x220\\\" \\x61\\x6c\\x74=\\\"\\x22 /\\x3e\\x20<a\\x20\\x68\\x72\\x65f=\\\"\".e_BASE.\"\\x75\\x73er\\x2eph\\x70?\\x69d\\x2e\".${${\"\\x47L\\x4fB\\x41\\x4c\\x53\"}[\"fy\\x63\\x79r\\x79\\x63\\x65\\x75\"]}.\"\\\">\".${${\"\\x47\\x4c\\x4fB\\x41\\x4c\\x53\"}[\"\\x64\\x66\\x76lt\\x79v\\x68h\\x68y\"]}[\"user_n\\x61me\"].\"\\x3c\\x2fa\\x3e\";";
    std::string result;
    f( input, input.size(), result );
    std::cout << "input: " << input << std::endl;
    std::cout << "output: " << result << std::endl;
}
```